# How to access a nested object in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Language used : Php with laravel

In an axios post request, i'm passing a form data object.

exemple of form data :

```
{
name : "Bruce"
work: { name : "actor", film : "pulp fiction" }
}
```

So here my $request contain the object.

It's working when i want to get the name with

```
public function test(Request $request)
  {
    $name = $request->get('name');

    echo ($name);
}
```

but how can i get work.name ?

Comment: BTW, you can simply use ``$request->name`` instead of ``$request->get('name')``.

Comment: `dd($request->all())` will give you all the inputs. You can access it like an array, since the result will be an array in the case of "work", with `$request->get('work')['name']`

Comment: you can access it like `$request->work['name']`

Comment: Thank you for answer everyone. So i'm getting a 500 error when i'm trying dd($request) so maybe i have an other error, i'm checking :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For nested objects like this

```
{
  name : "Bruce"
  work: { name : "actor", film : "pulp fiction" }
}
```

One of the way to access it is this.

```
public function test(Request $request)
{
    $workName = $request['work']['name']; // for work.name
    $name = $request['name']; // for name    
    echo $workName;

    //or
    $work = $request->input('work'); // $request->work;
    $name = $request->input('name'); // $request->name;
    $workName = $work['name'];
    echo $workName;
}
```

Comment: kindly, avoid answering duplicate questions :)

Comment: what if work is another object array like `work: [{name: 'someName', file: 'fileObjcekt'}...]

Comment: Then just do this $work[0]["name"}. use index to access the desired array's element